# How do WinRTs CaptureElement and MediaCapture class work together in detail?

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

it is pretty simple to display a live feed of a webcam in your application. Simply drop a CaptureElement on the UI, initialize a MediaCapture instance, assign it to the Source property of the CaptureElement and execute MediaCaptures "StartPreviewAsync" (more details can be found at http://blog.xyzzer.me/2012/01/22/displaying-webcam-preview-in-a-metro-app-using-winrt-and-xaml/).

Magic!

Well, a little bit too much magic for my taste.
How would I implement a control which does exactly the same?
Being used to .NET Framework Guidelines I look at the interface, the MediaCapture class offers and I expect SOMETHING the CaptureElement can use in order to receive and display the video feed. However, I do not find anything.
There must be some magic under the hood... but which one?
And how would I be able to develop the very same thing?

Back to day one and good bye to the comfortable times where ILDASM/Reflector gave you the full picture...

Answer (score 1):

The WinRT XAML Toolkit has a [CameraCaptureControl](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/CameraCaptureControl/CameraCaptureControl.cs) implemented now, that you can look at to see how to make something like the CameraCaptureUI and expand on to add whatever you need. If you can't do something that way - you can look at [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-extensions-sample-7b466096) on MSDN to see how to add various special effects using MFTs (Media Foundation Transforms) and Direct2D filters if you want to. Otherwise - you can use Media Foundation directly or [mixed with Direct3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858144/how-to-apply-image-effects-like-edge-detection-oncamera-stream-in-windows-8-app/9864817#9864817) to get virtually full access to the underlying media framework.