# How to apply image effects like edge detection oncamera stream in Windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, html, canvas, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am trying to apply image manipulation effects in Windows 8 app on camera feeds directly. 
I have tried a way using canvas and redrawing images after applying effects getting from webcam directly. But this approach works fine for basic effects but for effects like edge detection its creating large lag and flickering while using canvas approach.

Other way is to create MFT(media foundation transform) but it can be implemented in C about which i have no idea.

Can anyone tell me how can i achieve my purpose of applying effects on webcam stream directly in Windows 8 metro style app either by improving canvas approach so that large effects like edge detection don not have any issues or how can i apply MFT in C# since i have worked on C# language or by some other approach?

Comment: Can you tell me how did you manage to do the edge detection on the image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just played quite a bit in this area the last week and even considered writing a blog post about it. I guess this answer can be just as good.

You can go the MFT way, which needs to be done in C++, but the things you would need to write would not be much different between C# and C++. The only thing of note is that I think the MFT works in YUV color space, so your typical convolution filters/effects might behave a bit differently or require conversion to RGB. If you decide to go that route  On the C# application side the only thing you would need to do is to call MediaCapture.AddEffectAsync(). Well that and you need to edit your Package.appxmanifest etc., but let's go with first things first.

If you look at the [Media capture using webcam sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622) - it already does what you need. It applies a grayscale effect to your camera feed. It includes a C++ MFT project that is used in an application that is available in C# version. I had to apply the effect to a MediaElement which might not be what you need, but is just as simple - call MediaElement.AddVideoEffect() and your video file playback now applies the grayscale effect. To be able to use the MFT - you need to simply add a reference to the GrayscaleTransform project and add following lines to your appxmanifest:

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
    <InProcessServer>
      <Path>GrayscaleTransform.dll</Path>
      <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="GrayscaleTransform.GrayscaleEffect" ThreadingModel="both" />
    </InProcessServer>
  </Extension>
</Extensions>
```

How the MFT code works:

The following lines create a pixel color transformation matrix

```
float scale = (float)MFGetAttributeDouble(m_pAttributes, MFT_GRAYSCALE_SATURATION, 0.0f);
float angle = (float)MFGetAttributeDouble(m_pAttributes, MFT_GRAYSCALE_CHROMA_ROTATION, 0.0f);
m_transform = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Scale(scale, scale) * D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(angle);
```

Depending on the pixel format of the video feed - a different transformation method is selected to scan the pixels. Look for these lines:

```
m_pTransformFn = TransformImage_YUY2;
m_pTransformFn = TransformImage_UYVY;
m_pTransformFn = TransformImage_NV12;
```

For my sample m4v file - the format is detected as NV12, so it is calling TransformImage_NV12.

For pixels within the specified range (m_rcDest) or within the entire screen if no range was specified - the TransformImage_~ methods call TransformChroma(mat, &u, &v).
For other pixels - the values from original frame are copied.

TransformChroma transforms the pixels using m_transform. If you want to change the effect - you can simply change the m_transform matrix or if you need access to neighboring pixels as in an edge detection filter - modify the TransformImage_ methods to process these pixels.

This is one way to do it. I think it is quite CPU intensive, so personally I prefer to write a pixel shader for such operations. How do you apply a pixel shader to a video stream though? Well, I am not quite there yet, but I believe you can [transfer video frames](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wingameswithdirectx/thread/ffacd05c-6e9e-43bf-b691-99127240730c) to a DirectX surface fairly easily and call a pixel shader on them later. So far - I was able to transfer the video frames and I am hoping to apply the shaders next week. I might write a blog post about it. I took the meplayer class from the [Media engine native C++ playback sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Engine-Playback-ce1c82f0) and moved it to a template C++ DirectX project converted to a WinRTComponent library, then used it with a C#/XAML application, associating the swapchain the meplayer class creates with the SwapChainBackgroundPanel that I use in the C# project to display the video. I had to make a few changes in the meplayer class. First - I had to move it to a public namespace that would make it available to other assembly. Then I had to modify the swapchain it creates to a format accepted for use with a SwapChainBackgroundPanel:

```
        DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDesc = {0};
        swapChainDesc.Width = m_rcTarget.right;
        swapChainDesc.Height = m_rcTarget.bottom;
        // Most common swapchain format is DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8-UNORM
        swapChainDesc.Format = m_d3dFormat;
        swapChainDesc.Stereo = false;

        // Don't use Multi-sampling
        swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

        //swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_BACK_BUFFER | DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
        swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT; // Allow it to be used as a render target.
        // Use more than 1 buffer to enable Flip effect.
        //swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 4;
        swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
        //swapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_NONE;
        swapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH;
        swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;
        swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;
```

Finally - instead of calling CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow - I am calling CreateSwapChainForComposition and associating the swapchain with my SwapChainBackgroundPanel:

```
        // Create the swap chain and then associate it with the SwapChainBackgroundPanel.
        DX::ThrowIfFailed(
            spDXGIFactory.Get()->CreateSwapChainForComposition(
                spDevice.Get(),
                &swapChainDesc,
                nullptr,                                // allow on all displays
                &m_spDX11SwapChain)
            );

        ComPtr<ISwapChainBackgroundPanelNative> dxRootPanelAsSwapChainBackgroundPanel;

        // Set the swap chain on the SwapChainBackgroundPanel.
        reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(m_swapChainPanel)->QueryInterface(
            IID_PPV_ARGS(&dxRootPanelAsSwapChainBackgroundPanel)
            );

        DX::ThrowIfFailed(
            dxRootPanelAsSwapChainBackgroundPanel->SetSwapChain(m_spDX11SwapChain.Get())
            );
```

*EDIT follows

Forgot about one more thing. If your goal is to stay in pure C# - if you figure out how to capture frames to a WriteableBitmap (maybe by calling [MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700840.aspx) with a MemoryStream and then calling WriteableBitmap.[SetSource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsource.aspx) on the stream) - you can use [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) to process your images. It might not be top performance, but if your resolution is not too high or your frame-rate requirements are not high - it might just be enough. The project on CodePlex does not officially support WinRT yet, but I have a version that should work that you can try [here (Dropbox)](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1192076/WriteableBitmapEx.zip).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just need to know how will  MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync() will perform for my edge detection algorithm on camera feeds. I am using convolution filter. Will it be good enough performance for camera feed of 720*481? I will directly show the effects on the camera feeds.

Comment: Right, well, please do share what you find out!

Comment: A related article from Jeremiah Morrill is also available here: http://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/gpu-accelerated-media-effects-in-windows-8-metro/

Comment: Thank you!!! Your code solved me a problem with days. I would give you 1000 points if I could!!!

Comment: Additionally - [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-extensions-sample-7b466096) sample shows how to do MFT processing on the GPU using DirectX.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, MFTs need to be implemented in C++.  I believe that there is a media transform SDK sample which shows implementing some straightforward transforms from a metro style application.