# MFT Custom image Filters

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, ms-media-foundation

I am currently developing a Metro Style App which uses an MFT (Media Foundation Transform) to filter the webcam's video stream into grayscale, as demonstrated in [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622) sample.

However, now I want to apply other types of filters, such as exposure, hue, luminance, texture, [vignette](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignetting), etc. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858144/how-to-apply-image-effects-like-edge-detection-oncamera-stream-in-windows-8-app) answer says I am supposed to modify the TransformChroma method in order to achieve this. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get the Y value, I can only get the U and V. **How do I get the Y value in the formats NV12, YUY2, and UYVY?**

All help is greatly appreciated and I always accept an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to change the signature of the method (an poto take another parameter and modify the TransformImage_UYVY, TransformImage_YUY2 and TransformImage_NV12 methods to pass that parameter into the updated method. You would need to figure out how to extract that value for yourself though though. For example looking at this piece of code below you can see how the U and V values are extracted and that the Y value is split in two bytes - you would need to do some bit logic to join these. You can find descriptions of these formats online, e.g. [here](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php).

```
// Byte order is U0 Y0 V0 Y1
// Each WORD is a byte pair (U/V, Y)
// Windows is little-endian so the order appears reversed.
BYTE u = pSrc_Pixel[x] & 0x00FF;
BYTE v = pSrc_Pixel[x+1] & 0x00FF;

TransformChroma(mat, &u, &v);
```

Comment: Would this work, or is it backwards? `BYTE py = LO_NIBBLE(*pu) + (LO_NIBBLE(*pv) << 4);
 *pu = (HI_NIBBLE(*pu) << 4);
 *pv = (HI_NIBBLE(*pv) << 4);`

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you are trying to extract the Y value from U and V values, but it is not part of these. It would be more like WORD y = (pSrc_Pixel[x] & 0xFF00) | (pSrc_Pixel[x+1] >> 8); // or swap x and x+1.

Comment: But how do I update the image to reflect changes in the y variable after I have edited it?

Comment: Change TransformChroma(mat, &u, &v) to TransformChroma(mat, &y, &u, &v), then modify TransformChroma to modify the pixels. Right now UV is converted to a vector and has a matrix transform applied to it. You could use a bigger matrix or just update YUV values separately.

Comment: Is there a way to get the RGB values of each pixel without having to convert to/from YUV for every pixel?

Comment: I think video just comes in that format. If you want to do RGB you could use DirectX, do TransferVideoFrame to copy video frames to a D3D surface and then use a pixel shader to do the actual filtering. Who knows - it might even perform better than an MFT...

Comment: I am very unfamiliar with DirectX. Where would I call TransferVideoFrame and what would I provide as its arguments?

Comment: It's fairly complicated to explain if you are unfamiliar with DirectX. Maybe this article which seems to use a slightly different approach might help you: http://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/gpu-accelerated-media-effects-in-windows-8-metro/

Comment: HIs example seems to be a lot more complex, and I am getting numerous syntax errors when I run it, which on further analysis, don't make much sense. Have you gotten it to work.

Comment: No, I have not really looked much at his code - just looked for TransferVideoFrame which I haven't found. I have used it in my code, but I can't share it.

Comment: I understand. Would the DirectX TransferVideoFrame implementation require a complete rewrite of the code? Or would I simply have to replace TransformChroma with something else?

Comment: It's pretty much a rewrite. You'd need to do DirectX XAML interop if your app is XAML and Media Framework for video + DX/MF interop to get video into a pixel shader. I'm not an expert though so you might want to check msdn forums and look for a Media Framework specialist.