# Perform live video stream processing from CaptureElement & MediaCapture

Tags: c#, video, windows-8, windows-runtime, video-processing

In my Windows 8 Store Application, I tend to perform live video stream processing (Face detection for example).

---

### Technique 1

In my previous Windows 7 application, I was able to use the following technique ([Camera Face Detection in C# Using Emgu CV (OpenCV in .NET) and WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/462527/Camera-Face-Detection-in-Csharp-Using-Emgu-CV-Open)) to perform live video processing. The technique was, **having a fixed period timer callback, to actively query image buffer from camera object**.

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image<Bgr,Byte> currentFrame = capture.QueryFrame();
    // Perform image processing based on currentFrame
```

---

### Technique 2

Another technique I had used before in [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html) is that, I will install a camera buffer preview callback on camera itself. **The camera will periodically trigger the callback, by passing along the captured camera buffer**. From there, I can perform image processing.

```
public abstract void onPreviewFrame (byte[] data, Camera camera)
{
    // Perform image processing based on data
```

---

However, in articles which talks about video processing for **Windows 8 Store Application**, they are mostly using built-in processing functions

- [How to rotate captured video (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868174.aspx)
- [How to add video stabilization effect to captured video (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868169.aspx)

**None of them demonstrate how to access raw camera captured buffer, iterate the buffer pixel by pixel.**

I believe I need to make use of `CaptureElement & MediaCapture` according to

http://blog.xyzzer.me/2012/01/22/displaying-webcam-preview-in-a-metro-app-using-winrt-and-xaml/

> This method is great if you just want to see the webcam input or
>   capture it to a file with no hassle. If you want to process the video
>   in real time or overlay some other UI components – enter…
>
> The CaptureElement & MediaCapture Way

However, the author doesn't elaborate more after that. (I hope he does so :)

Any hint how to perform live video stream processing from CaptureElement & MediaCapture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could try first is MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync which I think also only scenarios where that photo will be compressed, but you could probably fairly quickly decode it back into a WriteableBitmap and do some processing on its pixels. You probably aren't going to process too many frames per second that way though.

The better way to do it would probably be to use MediaCapture.AddEffectAsync() and write a Media Foundation Transform (MFT) in C++ that would process the video and somehow communicate the results back to the app.

Comment: I went through MFT info from the link http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-777T found in your blog. Any idea on MFT can be implemented in C#, as all my video buffer processing code right now is in C#? Wondering why Microsoft make camera buffer processing so difficult in Metro compared to its desktop's.

Comment: I think MFTs are C++ only and I would speculate that it is because it needs maximum performance and the .NET for Windows Store apps has plenty of more basic features missing that need to be implemented before this. Overall though they seem to be pushing for development of games and media applications using the native stack - first because it is already available and second - so people learn and build more high performance apps.

Comment: Also check this [older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858144/how-to-apply-image-effects-like-edge-detection-oncamera-stream-in-windows-8-app) I answered for some brain dump on MFTs.

Comment: thanks for the resource. 1783 lines of Grayscale.cpp code just to perform gray scale conversion? :( btw, do you think Grayscale c++ project able to consume functions directly from OpenCV Windows 7 DLL? As few days ago I try to use EgmuCV (C# wrapper) + OpenCV DLL in Windows Store App. It won't work cause Windows Store App cannot use Windows 7 DLL?! I am not sure thing is going to be different, if I use Windows 7 DLL in MFT C++ code?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but that Grayscale thing was handling multiple video stream formats and well - it just seems like it's not so straightforward to write an MFT. The upside is that once you figure out where the actual processing code is - it is just a few lines of code that you need to modify to change how the frames are processed. If your library doesn't work on Win8 in an app - it shouldn't work either in an MFT.

Comment: OK. I manage to re-compile OpenCV under Win 8 to static library. The GrayscaleTransform.dll is manage to access certain functions in OpenCV right now.