# Resume camera when i come back to app in windows 8/RT/8.1?

Tags: javascript, windows, html

I am windows store app developer, My question is how to resume camera? Basically camera is first page of my app and when i switch to some other functionality in the Tablet/PC and when I come back to the app then camera page getting freezed.

Thanks

Comment: Post the code. Without that how are we supposed to know?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264463/suspend-camera-when-user-switches-away-from-app-and-resume-camera-when-user-swi

Comment: Actually we are using "MediaCapture" class object. How to start preview of the camera when it comes from background to the foreground mode.