# How to stream Wireless WiFi IP camera video into my application?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I would like to develop an interface to a Wireless WiFi IP camera and stream its video in a frame in my application. I never did such a thing and would appreciate any pointers.

how should I approach this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at my [MJPEG Decoder](http://mjpeg.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.  You'll find source + binaries for almost every Windows platform (WinForms, WPF, Windows Runtime, etc.) along with samples.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple options that you may consider. However, it is very important to define the stream/source of video transmitter.

- [How to use a web cam in C# with .NET Framework 4.0 and Microsoft Expression Encoder 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202464/How-to-use-a-WebCam-in-C-with-the-NET-Framework-4)
- [Perform live video stream processing from CaptureElement & MediaCapture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12836017/1437962)
- [Video Panel control XAML description for Viewing Webcam in WPF](http://www.microsoftfaqs.com/Articles/14911930/Video_Panel_control_XAML_description_for_Viewing_Webcam_in_WPF)

Comment: Hi, 
I need to camera to be wireless is this requirement changes your answer?
Thanks,
Eitan

Comment: having wireless connection does not change anything, except the channel of communication.

Comment: Looking at the links, it looks to me they are more to do about webcam connected to the PC. I am also looking for solution for Windows Application Store environment.