# zxing get image stream

Tags: c#, uwp, qr-code, zxing

I would like to get the video stream from [QR library zxing for UWP](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile).

I intend to duplicate the stream into two outputs. So the underlying stream can be passed through a `Gaussian Blur Filter` and the stream on top will be shown clearly as a quadratic geometry on the center of the screen (no distortion, just like a 'cut out window'). This gives the effect, that the user is scanning and focusing on the non-blurred area (in the middle of the screen) and the surrounding is blurred.

I intend to do the blurring with either the `Lumia SDK` or the new `Composition API`, which are both supposed to be very fast with video manipulation.

How can I achieve this? This would definitely be a nice eye-candy for QR scanners, while not being too heavy on CPU/GPU.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to get the video stream from QR library zxing for UWP

Based on the source code of `ZXing.Mobile`, there is no existing API to get video stream from `ZXing`, but we can implement it by ourselves.

Let's see how Zxing.mobile did that:

1. In the [`MobileBarcodeScanner.Scan` method](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Source/ZXing.Net.Mobile.WindowsUniversal/MobileBarcodeScanner.cs#L54), it actually navigates to the `ScanPage` view

   ```
   rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ScanPage), new ScanPageNavigationParameters 
   {//......
   }
   ```
2. The [`ScanPage`](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Source/ZXing.Net.Mobile.WindowsUniversal/ScanPage.xaml#L11) view, the `ZXingScannerControl` control will be used to bear the primary task:

   ```
   <zxing:ZXingScannerControl x:Name="scannerControl">

   </zxing:ZXingScannerControl>
   ```
3. In the [`StartScanningAsync` method](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Source/ZXing.Net.Mobile.WindowsUniversal/ZXingScannerControl.xaml.cs#L174), the principle is using `MediaCapture` API to start camera preview and calling `GetPreviewFrameAsync` method to get preview frame in a timer, this frame can be convert to `LuminanceSource`, by using `BarcodeReader.Decode` method to decode barcode within this image.

   ```
   // Set the capture element's source to show it in the UI
       captureElement.Source = mediaCapture;

       // Start the preview
       await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
   ```

   ......

   ```
   SoftwareBitmapLuminanceSource luminanceSource = null;

           try
           {
               // Get preview 
               var frame = await mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame);

               // Create our luminance source
               luminanceSource = new SoftwareBitmapLuminanceSource(frame.SoftwareBitmap);
   ```

   ......

   ```
    ZXing.Result result = null;

           try
           {
               // Try decoding the image
               if (luminanceSource != null)
                   result = zxing.Decode(luminanceSource);
   ```

> So the underlying stream can be passed through a Gaussian Blur Filter and the stream on top will be shown clearly as a quadratic geometry on the center of the screen (no distortion, just like a 'cut out window').

What you could try first is [`MediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700840.aspx), there is a similar discussion in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836017/perform-live-video-stream-processing-from-captureelement-mediacapture)

If you want to show a quadratic geometry on the center of the screen, you could place a `Canvas` to contain these geometry objects, see the official [Basic face tracking sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BasicFaceTracking/cs/Scenario1_TrackInWebcam.xaml.cs#L327)

XAML:

```
 <CaptureElement Name="CamPreview" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
 <Canvas Name="VisualizationCanvas" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
```

Code Behind:

```
private void SetupVisualization(Windows.Foundation.Size framePizelSize, IList<DetectedFace> foundFaces)
    {
            this.VisualizationCanvas.Children.Clear();

            double actualWidth = this.VisualizationCanvas.ActualWidth;
            double actualHeight = this.VisualizationCanvas.ActualHeight;

            if (this.currentState == ScenarioState.Streaming && foundFaces != null && actualWidth != 0 && actualHeight != 0)
            {
                double widthScale = framePizelSize.Width / actualWidth;
                double heightScale = framePizelSize.Height / actualHeight;

                foreach (DetectedFace face in foundFaces)
                {
                    // Create a rectangle element for displaying the face box but since we're using a Canvas
                    // we must scale the rectangles according to the frames's actual size.
                    Rectangle box = new Rectangle();
                    box.Width = (uint)(face.FaceBox.Width / widthScale);
                    box.Height = (uint)(face.FaceBox.Height / heightScale);
                    box.Fill = this.fillBrush;
                    box.Stroke = this.lineBrush;
                    box.StrokeThickness = this.lineThickness;
                    box.Margin = new Thickness((uint)(face.FaceBox.X / widthScale), (uint)(face.FaceBox.Y / heightScale), 0, 0);

                    this.VisualizationCanvas.Children.Add(box);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: wow, first thank you, I'm stunned, this is quite some text you wrote here. I will have a look into this and try it. I will post my results as soon, as I get some.

Comment: @user3079834 no problem, this is not easy to digest all things quickly. Waiting for your good news:)